# Visual studio 2010 - How to use opengl 2.0 API?

Tags: opengl

I'm learning GLSL. I tried to use a function glCreateShader. but there is no glCreateShader function. as i know, glCreateShader function is available in Opengl2.0

How can I use Opengl 2.0 in Visual studio 2010 c++ win32 project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would advice that you use an extension library such as [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/). When including its header, you will find all the functions you'll need. And what's more, you can easily check which extensions are available on your platform.